# Pod was implicitly rejected because its architectures 'arm64' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 arm64'

Tags: xcode, swift2, ios9, cocoapods, swifty-json

While these cocoapods were working previously, I'm getting these errors since I tried to make Xcode 7.3.1 work with iOS 10 device. Now even when I run my project on iOS 9 device, it's can't find the modules i.e. SwiftyJSON and warns arm64 architecture doesn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 arm64'. You can click on the link below to see the screenshot of errors. Any ideas?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRl3O.png)